# underscore.js - Is there a function that produces an array thats the difference of two arrays?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Looking for a function in underscore.js that will take 2 arrays and return a new array of unique values?  Something like _without

```
_.without([0, 1, 3, 9], [1, 3]);
```

I would like `=> [0,9]` returned

It appears _without's 2nd arg is a list of values, not an array.  Anyone out there know
if underscore has the specific function I'm looking for? Or can I take an exisitng array and covert it to values the function expects.

Thanks,
~ck in San Diego

Comment: thanks for the edit Jeff. typo.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`_.without.apply(_, [arr1].concat(arr2))`

`[[0, 1, 3, 9]].concat([1, 3])` is `[[0, 1, 3, 9], 1, 3]`;

`_.without.apply(_, [[0, 1, 3, 9], 1, 3])` is `_.without([0, 1, 3, 9], 1, 3)`

You've got a perfectly good `_.without` method. So just convert an array into a list of values you can pass into a function. This is the purpose of `Function.prototype.apply`

Comment: Both solutions are correct however, I like the that you do the conversion to the style of arguments that the function needs. Well done!!!

Comment: This is deprecated, should use _.difference

Answer (score 41):

The [`_.difference`](http://underscorejs.org/#difference) function should give you what you're looking for:

```
_.difference([0, 1, 3, 9], [1, 3]); // => [0, 9]
```

Comment: One function I don't see is one that in the case of ([0,1,3,9], [1,3,12]) gives [0,9,12].  I think that's "disjunction"

Answer (score 4):

```
var result = _.reject([0, 1, 3, 9], function(num) {
                return _.include([1, 3], num);
            });
```

Comment: Any description what your snippet is doing?

Comment: @kaiser: `reject` takes a list and a function that acts as a "truth test" to ask whether each item should be rejected. In this case that function is specified to check whether the given item is included in the list `[1, 3]`. If it is, it will return `true`, and `reject` will reject the value. Back at the top level, `reject` is given the original list and will return a new list without any rejected values.

Answer (score 1):

Lo-Dash is extended Underscore and here is what you need: http://lodash.com/docs#xor

**_.xor**

> Creates an array that is the symmetric difference of the provided arrays. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference.

```
_.xor([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4]);
// → [3, 5, 4]
```