# underscore.js with two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have the following array:

```
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']
```

My goal is to remove from it unexpected values:

I tried to do it with underscore `without` function like below:

```
_.without(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'], 'bbb', 'ccc');
```

It works fine, but unfortunately it does not work with array:

```
_.without(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'], ['bbb', 'ccc']);
```

I've googled a bit and find the post [underscore.js - Is there a function that produces an array thats the difference of two arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722254/underscore-js-is-there-a-function-that-produces-an-array-thats-the-difference)

But in my case this one also does not work, namely it returns somthing like that:

```
"a","a","a"
```

when I tired to use apply function.

Can some one suggest what need to be done to remove all unexpected keys with array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [`_.difference`](http://underscorejs.org/#difference)?

```
_.difference(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'], ['bbb', 'ccc']);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Accepted. Before,I've briefly tried the following function. But actually I was a bit surprised why the following example _.difference([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10]); skip 10. But now I see that it is described in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, that's how it can be done with `_.without`:

```
var source = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'];
var blacklist = ['bbb', 'ddd'];
var without = _.without.apply(_, [source].concat(blacklist));
```